# Access query parameters in IDbCommandTreeInterceptor (EF 6.4)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When a query is processed by the IDbCommandTreeInterceptor, I'd like to be able to access the parameter values in the query itself.

I'm doing a query like the below and would like to be able to access and change the "testname" parameter inside the interceptor.

```
context.TestEntities.FirstOrDefault(t.Name == "testname");
```

Here is the interceptor

```
public class Example : IDbCommandTreeInterceptor
{
    public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    {
        if (interceptionContext.Result.DataSpace != DataSpace.CSpace) { return; }

        if (interceptionContext.Result.CommandTreeKind != DbCommandTreeKind.Query) { return; }

        var queryCommand = interceptionContext.Result as DbQueryCommandTree;

        if (queryCommand == null) { return; }

        var newQuery = queryCommand.Query.Accept(new TestVisitor());

        interceptionContext.Result = new DbQueryCommandTree(queryCommand.MetadataWorkspace, queryCommand.DataSpace, newQuery);
    }

    private class TestVisitor : DefaultExpressionVisitor
    {
        public override DbExpression Visit(DbScanExpression expression)
        {
            // Can get the entity type.
            var entityType = expression.Target.ElementType as EntityType;

            // Can get the context.
            var context = expression.Target.EntityContainer;

            // Get the entity set.
            var entitySet = context.GetEntitySetByName(expression.Target.ToString(), true);

            // Need to be access the query parameters here?

            return expression;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: When do you want to change this parameter value? And just once or more often?

Comment: Just once, I'd like to convert datetimes to UTC during queries.

Comment: @Rtype Did you end up solving this? Also struggling with the poorly documented EF Interception API

Comment: Sadly not, I wasn't able to find a way around it.